# Google Maps won't start on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, crash, google, maps

I tap on the icon for the app, the splash screen appears, and then it promptly crashes back to the home screen without a trace.

I've updated to the latest version of the app and the latest version of iOS but that hasn't helped.

I've tried turning the phone off and back on again and that hasn't helped either.

I'd like to try uninstalling and re-installing the app, but it's not clear how to do that from the phone itself.  I've tried to do so from iTunes on my PC, but it warns me that "This app will not be deleted from any iOS device that synchronizes with your iTunes library."

I'm at a loss.  I guess what I'm eventually going to have to do is just upgrade to the latest iPhone since it doesn't look like this old version is going to receive any more support.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just use Apple Maps. After fixing some iOS 6-era bugs, it's great and Apple's a lot better with privacy then Google is.

Comment: ...but it's still hopeless at finding anywhere. Can't find addresses in my contacts, have to make sure I look them up on Maps on OS X by postcode, otherwise when I'm in my car, trying to navigate over Apple CarPlay... can't find the damn thing. Not all with Google is perfect, though - since yesterday it seems to think I live 200 miles from where I do :(

Comment: I've been using Apple Maps as a workaround, but it's definitely not as good.  My biggest frustration with it is just that it never gets the orientation right in relation to my direction of travel.  I always have to sit there in my car spinning the stupid thing around in circles trying to figure out where it wants me to go!

Comment: Still suffering from this problem.  I doesn't seem like either Google OR Apple care (I've tried filing bug reports with both of them).  I'm missing the trip planner from Google Maps for finding bus routes home.  :-/  I'm tempted to post "both companies suck, and nobody is going to help you unless you cave in and buy the latest phone" as an answer and then accept that.  That may very well be correct!

Comment: I've gone ahead and done this since it's clearly the case.

Comment: Also a funny story:  Last week I was going to a Malaysian restaurant called Kedai with some friends.  Google Maps on my friend's phone got the directions right.  Apple maps on my phone tried to take me to Malaysia...  lol